# publish data in Facebook

Tags: php, javascript, sdk

I am having problem while posting data through my app on Facebook when user is not login into Facebook.

I am using javascript SDK,

```
FB.api(\'/profile_id(anyid)/feed\',
    \'post\',
    { message: \'hello dear offline msg\' }

    );
```

It is working if user is login into Facebook.

Comment: users must be logged into your app and specifically allowed your app to post on there feeds, read the docs...

Comment: yeah Lawerence they have already allowed the permission included perm publish_stream, read_stream, now actually i wants to post msg when user is not currently logged in, offline posting from my site.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post to facebook without **active** session.

Comment: How can i activate user session using JavaScript sdk, from my site on behalf user to post message, without login manually in Facebook to create session

Comment: @param: you cannot. User (your site visitor) should be logged in at facebook. You can do that only using server-side code, not js sdk.

Comment: but the user must still be logged in, this is obviously to protect users from what your actually trying to achieve. if a site posted to my wall without me specifically allowing it (me pressing some button at the time, knowing something will be posted) i would remove & block your app.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: since he has retrieved `publish_stream` permission - he **can** perform offline posts without any user interaction (it is violates TOS probably, but technically it is correct and possible)

Comment: @param: is it possible with JavaScript SDK to perform offline posting ? to user wall, from my(any) site , when user remain logged out from Facebook